# Reading dynamically created hidden field from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind

I am adding a hidden filed to a table cell in code behind like this

```
              HtmlTableCell tCellJson= new HtmlTableCell();
              HiddenField hdnJson = new HiddenField();
              hdnJson.ID = "hdnJson"+ count;

              tCellJson.Controls.Add(hdnJson);
              tRow.Cells.Add(tCellJson);
```

and now when i am trying to get it from code behind i am not getting that hidden field control  from code behind,i am doing this

```
int count=0
  string controlname = "hdnJson" + ++Count;
  HiddenField hdnJson =(HiddenField)tbleFileList.FindControl(controlname);
```

My question is how to get value of hidden field that is added from Code behind?

I have seen the Page Source where hidden Field is added and Id of that hiddenfield is **hdnJson1**

Comment: Need to know what the value of `count` is in first code block.  Also need to know which part of page life cycle each of the code blocks is occurring in, `Page_Load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the code that dynamically adds the HiddenField inside the PreInit event, and you should be good to go.

Check the MSDN article on [the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Especially the PreInit event section:

> Use this event for the following:
>
> ...
>
> - Create or re-create dynamic controls.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // whatever other code you have up here

    HtmlTableCell tCellJson= new HtmlTableCell();
    HiddenField hdnJson = new HiddenField();
    hdnJson.ID = "hdnJson"+ count;

    tCellJson.Controls.Add(hdnJson);
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCellJson);
}
```